# Incorporating library into script?

Tags: python, pyglet

I'd like to incorporate Pyglet's sound and windowing abilities into my script. Is there any way to add it to the script so it won't need to be installed? I realize this will use a lot of memory and take longer to start, but it will be more convenient than having to install pyglet for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [same hack](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/src/8573473debb9/_pytest/genscript.py) that used in pytest library, it generates a script like [this](https://github.com/selectel/pyte/blob/develop/runtests.py).